# how to store Android database with variable number of attributes per row

Tags: android, database, sqlite

For my Android app, I want to save data using sqlite with this format:

name, date, attr1, attr2, attr3,...

These are the requirements:

1. each date can only contain each name once
2. there can be a variable number of attributes(numbers) for each name
3. each specific name has the same number of attributes

The app will be used to track events throughout the day. Events can have zero or more numeric properties.

The questions are: is sqlite the best way to store things here? If so how do I design my database? What other ways are there to store this kind of data?

Answer (score 3):

> **is sqlite the best way to store things here?**

This will depend on a number of other factors, such as how the data will be queried and used, the volume of transactions, data growth and retention, etc.  From what you've described, though, SQLite is a great option, offering functionality out-of-the-box that supports some of your requirements directly, and is commonly used in such cases.

If you don't have much experience with relational databases, implementing this functionality may seem difficult at first, but like learning a new language or framework, it will get easier with time.

> **If so how do I design my database?**

Let's step through each of your enumerated requirements...

> 1. each date can only contain each name once

SQLite supports the `UNIQUE` constraint.  For example, if your columns were named `name` and `date`, you could add the following to your `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```
    UNIQUE(name, date)
```

*(A more complete `CREATE TABLE` statement is in the next example below, and it includes this constraint.)*

This constraint prevents the insertion of rows with name/date pairs that already exist. Using [`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html), if you attempt to insert a row into the table with a duplicate name/date pair, a [`SQLiteConstraintException`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteConstraintException.html) will be thrown at runtime.  You will need to handle this exception in your java code.

> 2. there can be a variable number of attributes(numbers) for each name

This is a textbook case for [normalizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) the database, putting your data into multiple tables.  For example:

```
CREATE TABLE names (
    name_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    date DATETIME,
    UNIQUE(name, date));

CREATE TABLE attrs (
    name_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    attr_value INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(attr_value) REFERENCES names(name_id));
```

Your queries that retrieve attribute data would then [`JOIN`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) the two tables.  Since you indicated that "Events can have zero or more numeric properties", a [`LEFT OUTER JOIN`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join) might be most appropriate, as it will return names and dates even if there are no attributes.

Here's an example query, by name:

```
SELECT n.name, n.date, a.attr_value
FROM names AS n
LEFT OUTER JOIN attrs AS a 
    ON n.name_id = a.name_id
WHERE n.name = 'SMITH'
ORDER BY n.name, n.date, a.attr_value;
```

This query would return results like the following:

```
name              date         attr_value
---------------   ----------   ------------
SMITH             2015-02-13   1027
SMITH             2015-02-13   4426
SMITH             2015-02-13   8390
SMITH             2015-02-20   4426
SMITH             2015-02-20   8152
SMITH             2015-02-20   9328
```

You can then iterate through and process these results in java.  If your results include multiple names and/or dates, then in your loop you should keep track of the last used name and date.  If the name/date in the current record is the same, the attribute belongs to the current one.  If the name/date is different, then this is a new one.

Note that this approach to your database design is flexible, allowing you to query on the attributes, for instance, to see what name/date pairs are associated.

Also note that there is a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint on the `attrs` table, meaning that if you attempt to insert a record into that table with a `name_id` that does not exist in the `names` table, a [`SQLiteConstraintException`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteConstraintException.html) will be thrown at runtime.  You will need to handle this exception in your java code.

> 3. each specific name has the same number of attributes

You will need to accommodate this requirement in your java code, probably doing some checks in the database prior to performing an `INSERT`.

> **What other ways are there to store this kind of data?**

Flat files, JSON, XML, third-party data stores (with their own libraries), to name a few.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I think the best way to achieve your requirement is to use sqlite and to solve your problem you can have 3 columns only. One for the name and one for the date and the other contains a **JSON** array that represents the rest of the attributes.